# Detect and trace moved row event in Google Apps Script for Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet where each row is dependent on the row above (cells in each row have formulas referencing cells in the row above). Now I want to be able to move an entire row (by clicking and dragging the row number) without breaking the references. I want all the references to be updated so that each row is dependent on the row that is above it after the change, not the row that was above it before the change.

I have a function that updates the formulas. I just need to figure out where the row was moved from. I have an `onEdit(e)` function in which I use the event to determine where the row was moved **to**. I only need to find out where it was moved **from**. Is it possible to get this information somehow?

Comment: Since the moved row would have a formula which would still reference the row above it before the move, you can probably use that to determine where was it moved from!

Comment: Also, if you could include your code it would be much more helpful in understanding what you are exactly trying to accomplish.

Comment: Oh, that's right! Didn't think about that. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding code I'm not sure what I would include. What I was doing was a GUI operation. Do you mean I should have added the code for the part that I figured out? Because the only thing I needed was a way to get where the active range was before the row was inserted. but the event doesn't hold that information. And I didn't have any code at all for that.